# How can I set a jQuery tab number that's present in an ASP.NET MVC model?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.NET MVC view on which I've placed jQuery tabs. I'm loading the tabs using:

```
function getContentTab(index) {  
    var url='<% = Url.Content("~/Books/GetBookTab") %>/' + index; 
    ...
}
```

I have stored the user's default tab selection in the model associated with this view.

My question is this, how can I set the tab number (index) with the number in my model data?

Thanks,

Arnold

Comment: To be more clear, I'm using the following code to set the tab:

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            getContentTab (1);
        });

So, instead of the hard-coded 1 as an argument for getContentTab(), I want to use a number passed in by the model.

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#tabs").tabs(); 
      getContentTab(<%=this.Model.DefaultTabID %>); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Luke,

Sorry for the delay in getting back to this. This answer works for me!

Thanks